# Can I use any usb optical drives with my macbook air?

Tags: usb, optical-drive, macbook-air

For a macbook air, would you recommend buying any non-apple usb optical drives - or should I only buy apple's usb superdrive?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any drive should work fine, but you might not get some features like CD sharing.

Comment: It's a feature where you can share your optical drive with other Macs that don't have an optical drive. See here: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH4362